# OverrideDeadline in Job Scheduler

Tags: android

I'm using  `jobSchedular` with `setMinimumLatency` and any network type is required but as i read from the documentation if the requirement doesn't met and i want to force start services after a certain time i need to call `setOverrideDeadline` but even after calling it the service doesn't start if network constraints doesn't met.
I need to know how `setOverDeadline` works?

Here's snippet of my code:

```
  JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) App.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

        ComponentName mServiceComponent = new ComponentName(App.applicationContext, StartCycleServices.class);
        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(com.itaxi.Constants.START_CYCLE_JOB_ID, mServiceComponent);
        builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);
        builder.setPersisted(true);


        long remainingTime = 0;
        try {
            remainingTime = TimeUtil.getRemainingTime(Constants.StartCycle);
            builder.setMinimumLatency(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(remainingTime));

            builder.setOverrideDeadline(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(remainingTime + 1));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

setOverrideDeadline(10000): This will set a deadline for your job, now the current deadline is of 10 sec. Even if other requirements are not met, your task will start approximately when the stated time has passed. That means my task will get executed after 10 seconds. As 10 sec is the deadline to meet the requirements.

For more details you may refer the following link:
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2016/11/22/how-to-create-a-simple-repeating-job-using-jobscheduler-in-android/